# Does my wireless router lack port forwarding or am I missing something that should be obvious?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am a computer science student with a black, 150mbps Trendnet N150 Wireless Home Router (model TEW-711BR, see: http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=225_TEW-711BR ). My dad gave it to me, and I would like to try out some computer program networking and inter-program communication stuff with it.

My problem is that stuff like sending a c-string to another computer program via ip/socket won't seem to work outside my apartments local wifi network, so I might need either port forwarding or a non-local ipv6 address to send signals to processes over a non local network. My internet service provider, AT&T, does not offer ipv6 to my apartment, so I'm trying the port forwarding route, but I can't seem to find a port forwarding section anywhere in the router's settings and options. Can I get some help getting networking (port forwarding or anything else that might also work) to work? Is there no way for my router to do it, or am I missing the port forwarding setting?

All I see in the WiFi Router Settings are:

Main: LAN & DHCP Server, WAN, Password, Time, Dynamic DNS, IPv6

Wireless: Basic, Security, Advanced, WiFi Protected Setup

Status: Device Info, Log, Log Setting, Statistic, Wireless

Routing: Static, Dynamic, Routing Table

Access: Filter, Virtual Server, Special AP, DMZ, Firewall Rule

Management: SNMP, Remote Management, Capture Packets

Tools: Restart, Settings, Firmware, Ping Test

Wizard: Set your new password, Choose your time zone, Set LAN connection and DHCP Server, Set Internet connection, Set wireless LAN connection, Restart

As an alternative, is there another way to enable sending c strings between different Linux processes over the internet that isn't too difficult? Is there something obvious that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I'd look under firewall rule if I were you

Comment: It says: "Name: Action: (Allow/deny) Source: ip range start: ip range end: Destination: ip range start: ip range end: Protocol: (TCP/UDP) Add, Update, Delete, New". Is that it?

Comment: odd format, but looks like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does my wireless router lack port forwarding or am I missing something that should be obvious?

No, and yes, sort of. Port-forwarding on that router is under *Access → [Virtual Server](http://www.trendnet.com/emulators/TEW-711BR_V1.0R/virtual_server.htm)*:

[image: Screenshot of Trendnet virtual-server configuration screen]

Comment: ugh. <rant> This is why I hate router questions. Would it hurt to follow a standard? Virtual server means something else in web-server config, so... bad dev, no scooby snack for you!</rant>

Comment: Are you thinking of a virtual *host*?

Comment: Probably. Still, non standard names suck ;p

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "Virtual Server: Another name for port forwarding used by some routers." Got it... Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. My D-Link router is similar; it’s port-forwarding section is also called “Virtual Server” and it’s port-triggering section is called “Applications”.